Mean hitting time of position-dependent random walk
The question
I am interested in a continuous-time random walk on $K$ states, numbered $0$ to $(K - 1)$. For each $k$:

I call $p_k$ the transition rate from state $k$ to state $(k + 1)$;
I call $n_k$ the transition rate from state $k$ to state $(k - 1)$.

We can easily encode boundary conditions as:

$n_0 = 0$ [state $1$ is the minimum, cannot go further down];
$p_{K - 1} = 0$ [state $(K - 1)$ is the maxmum, cannot go further up].

Now, say we start at time $0$ on state $0$. What is the expected time to first encounter state $(K - 1)$? I know this as the "first passage time" problem, but I recall only seeing a solution in the discrete, balanced case (random walk goes in discrete steps, every step has a 1/2 probability of going up, 1/2 of going down).
The context
I am trying to get to a (very, very rough) estimate for the mean time to failure of a distributed system. In a distributed system, the application is compromised only when a threshold of servers (e.g., 20%) fails at the same time. Here I am modeling a server as a two-states continuous-time Markov chain:

A correctly operating server has a given mean time to failure;
A failed server has a given mean time to recovery.

This easily translates to the above problem, with state $k$ representing $k$ servers simultaneously experiencing a failure:

We transition to $(k + 1)$ if a correct server fails before any failed server is recovered;
We transition to $(k - 1)$ if a failed server is recovered before any correct server fails.

The AI response
I admit it, I did ask Copilot before coming here. It very confidently spit out that the expected time to first encounter state $(K - 1)$ is $T_{K - 1}$, with
$$
T_0 = 0
$$
and
$$
T_k = \frac{1}{p_{k - 1}} + \frac{n_{k - 1}}{p_{k - 1}} T_{k - 1}
$$
I tried to ask more, but it couldn't explain why it came to that answer, nor provide a meaningful reference to where it found such an answer. I have no clue if it is correct (my intuition alone does not help), but it might serve as a familiar pointer for someone more experienced than me in this domain.

I suggest you check the book "Markov Chains" by James R. Norris, where he explains how to obtain mean hitting times by solving linear equations (recurrence relations). I believe the AI response is not correct, as the linear system should involve higher degrees. Specifically, we have:
\begin{equation*}
p_0 T_0 - p_0 T_1 = 1, \quad -n_i T_{i-1} + (n_i+p_i) T_{i} - p_i T_{i+1} = 1, \quad \forall i \in \{ 1, \cdots, K - 2 \}, \quad T_{K-1} = 0.
\end{equation*}
